# Variable affecting its parent variable

Tags: javascript

The title might seems weird, 
but I don't really know how to describe this situation as I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

Here's the code :

```
a={};
var b=a;
b['a']='x';
console.log(a);
```

the result will be:

```
Object { a="x"}
```

shouldn't it be a blank object because I set 'x' to variable b only ?

Comment: If you would like a copy of the `Object`, that'll [take a bit more work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/122102).

Comment: Welcome to Object Oriented Programming!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` contains a *reference* to an object, like this:

```
+-----+        +--------------+
|  a  |------->| (the object) |
+-----+        +--------------+
```

So when you do:

```
var b = a;
```

Now you have two variables referring to the ***same*** object.

```
+-----+
|  a  |---+
+-----+   |    +--------------+
          +--->| (the object) |
+-----+   |    +--------------+
|  b  |---+
+-----+
```

So naturally, any changes you make to that object (adding a property to it, in your case) are visible through either reference.

Comment: never expected such a detail explanation,thank you very much,
finally understand this :D

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but why exactly does `b` have an almost twice as long reference line? Couldn't you better make them as long? :P

Comment: @BalusC: :-) I find it surprisingly hard to "see" ASCII-art, even though I love it. I've removed the extra line, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a reference to `a` so that is a normal behavior. To avoid that you need to make a clone. For example, using jQuery framework you could simple do: `var b = $.extend(true, {}, a};`